# Assign data to a variable in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have this code,

```
$(function() {
    //var asd = '<?php $regions_list_full; ?>';
    var projects = [
        {
            value: "jquery",
            label: "jQuery",
            desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
            //icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
        },
        {
            value: "jquery-ui",
            label: "jQuery UI",
            desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
            //icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
        },
        {
            value: "sizzlejs",
            label: "Sizzle JS",
            desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
            //icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
        }
    ];


    $( "#find" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: projects,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#find" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#find" ).val( ui.item.label );
            //$( ".module h1" ).val( ui.item.value );
            $(":header.title").html(ui.item.value);
            //$( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
            //$( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon );

            return false;
        }
    })
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
    });
```

actually this is from the autocomplete of `jQueryUI`, and I have an array of values which are fetched from the database. What I want is to replace my values into the `var projects =[{value:asd}]` such that my suggestions of the autocomplete will be the data from the database. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `source: projects`  you probably want to define a function for the source using an AJAX call like this

```
$( "#search_address" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/path/to/script',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'whatever you need here', // i.e. term value
            dataFilter: function (data, type) {
                // do whatever you need to here to change data into proper autocomplete array format
                // if JSON data is already in correct format you can just do this.
                response($parseJSON.(data));
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // handle error here
            },
            success: function(data) {
                // maybe check for case of empty data object here (i.e. successful URL request, but no data returned)
                return data;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now you typically want to limit the number of results returned by your API (maybe 10 or 20 records at most), as it is likely a bad UI experience to have 1000 items show up in autocomplete.  On a good autocomplete the number of results should decrease dramatically after a few letters have been types in.  This also make you script perform much better in that you are only processing a handful of returned records. For the same reason, you may also want to use the `minLength` property of `autocomplete` to not even bother starting the request until X number of characters are entered.

Comment: What if the data is already in the page, how would I assign the variable projects' value such that it's new value is no longer manually encoded value but from the page itself.

Comment: @CHiRiLo The approach would be similar.  You could approach this in a couple of ways.  If the data on the page is static (i.e. it doesn't change between times when the autocompletes may be called).  You could pre-calculate the data into a variable and use that variable for source, much like you are doing now.  Alternatively, you could make a custom source function like I have shown and calculate the data-value on-the-fly with each repeated function call.  Performance-wise, I think the first approach would be best if the content is not changing between page loads.

Comment: So you're saying I can simply store my array of data into a variable and then use it as the source for my autocomplete? I mean, my data consists is about 100 items. Unlike from what is shown above where the value of the source: projects is manually inputted, I want to have only a single input, from which the data then will be populated once the autocomplete is used.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by single input. At the end of the day, the value passed to source, whether it be via variable or function, needs to be an array in the required format.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`source: projects,`

to

`source: url_to_script`

Form which script you'll send your json. See ***[this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote)***. If you see the source code, you'll see that in `source` property they use `source: search.php`.

Similarly, you can use your own script path and return a json data from that script, where that data will coming from server.

Comment: Is there anyway I could just assign values to a certain variable inside the jquery function so that I can easily replace the source for instance source: new_var, new_var contains data fetched from the database?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery autocomplete will send a a querystring along to the url that you provide in the `source:` url , this query string will be `term`  so remember that , because I don't think autocomplete docs tell you that , then from there you use the term querysting to query the database and send back items that start with term ,  You do not request every row in the database and store them in javascript variable, that would not make sense - what if there are 2,000,000 entries in the database?